# Install openssl with secp256k1 support on Centos

Tags: centos, openssl

I'm trying to run this on my CentOS: `openssl ecparam  -name secp256k1 -genkey`

And I'm getting: `unable to create curve (secp256k1)`

I guess I need to update my openssl. But not sure how that can be done. I do a `yum update openssl` and it's reporting `No Packages marked for Update`.

How to install `openssl` that support `secp256k1` on my CentOS?

**Update**: My `openssl version -a`:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
built on: Tue Apr  8 02:39:29 UTC 2014
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DPURIFY -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  dynamic
```

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1021898

Comment: Lol. Looks like a funny thread. I'm installing openssl from source right now.

Answer (score 2):

For legal issues it seems that Centos did not distribute `secp256k1`. Today CentOS does distribute `secp256k1`. Right now you can update `openssl` to the latest version and it will get in:

```
[root@pe1ivldopsdes04 ~]# openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DPURIFY -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DRC4_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  dynamic
[root@pe1ivldopsdes04 ~]# openssl ecparam -list_curves
  secp256k1 : SECG curve over a 256 bit prime field
  secp384r1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 384 bit prime field
  secp521r1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 521 bit prime field
  prime256v1: X9.62/SECG curve over a 256 bit prime field
```

Comment: @Phuong Can you mark this as the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of OpenSSL on CentOS 7 include secp256k1. If you are missing the curve, update OpenSSL on your system.

```
yum update openssl*
```